# Not comprehending PowerMod

Tags: bugs, number-theory, built-in-symbols

**Bug introduced in 10.3 or earlier and persisting through 11.3.0 or later**

 The bug is not present in 10.0.

---

By definition, PowerMod[a, 1/r, m] finds a modular rth root of a mod m.
Here's a pair of examples to illustrate my conundrum in 11.1.1/Win 10.

```
PowerMod[2488, 1/3, 10^4]
8992
8992^3 
727057727488
Mod[PowerMod[2488, 1/3, 10^4]^3, 10^4] == 2488
False
```

Maybe pertinent is that the value returned above, 8992, is not contained in the corresponding PowerModList values:

```
PowerModList[2488, 1/3, 10^4]
{242, 2742, 5242, 7742}
Mod[PowerModList[2488, 1/3, 10^4]^3, 10^4]
{2488, 2488, 2488, 2488}
```

Similarly (if not identically) for

```
PowerMod[91175, 1/3, 10^5]  
84375
84375^3
600677490234375
Mod[PowerMod[91175, 1/3, 10^5]^3, 10^5] == 91175
False
```

And, unlike the first example,

```
PowerModList[91175, 1/3, 10^5]  
{}
```

In both cases it appears that PowerModList is correct (  PowerModList[91175, 1/3, 10^5]  should not return anything, and it doesn't).

Much obliged for taking a look at this.

Comment: `8992` is wrong.  The `PowerModList[]` is correct.  I'm not sure what else to say.  I guess it's a bug?  -- OK, maybe this: It seems to fail when $a$ and $m$ are not relatively prime.

Comment: @Rabbit i also think that this is a bug. Please report this to Wolfram Support.

Comment: It seems to be calculating the answer as `Mod[2488^x,10^4]` where `x` is determined by `Solve[3 x == 1, x, Modulus -> EulerPhi[10^4]]`, which is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @HenrikSchumacher - I let Wolfram support know of this.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2 for explaining the behavior.

Comment: Wolfram case  4211704

Comment: Email from support@wolfram.com says this is fixed in 12.0, referencing [CASE:4555193].