# PowerModList anomaly

Tags: bugs, number-theory, built-in-symbols

This post is related to [Not comprehending PowerMod](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189325/not-comprehending-powermod).  Here the issue is that PowerModList, in v. 12.1 finds no cube roots of 1 Mod 10^60 - 1:

```
PowerModList[1, 1/3, 10^60 - 1]    gives {}, but 

Mod[(((10^60 - 1)/3) + 1)^3, 10^60 - 1] gives 1
```

PowerMod returns 1 for this. Thanks for checking  this out, and for correcting me if I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, please report this.

Comment: Wolfram support case 4549220.

Comment: In my MMA 12.2, `PowerModList` now returns `SystemException["PowerModListSizeExceeded", 1048576]`